# Print word document using c#

Tags: c#, ms-word, office-interop

I have this code to open a word file

```
int num = 0;
object fileName = FD.FileName;
object readOnly = false;
object isVisible = false;
object missing = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;

Word.Application WordApp = new Word.Application();
Word.Document aDoc = null;
WordApp.Visible = false;

aDoc = WordApp.Documents.Open(ref fileName,
                              ref missing, 
                              ref readOnly,
                              ref missing,
                              ref missing, 
                              ref missing, 
                              ref missing,
                              ref missing, 
                              ref missing,
                              ref missing,
                              ref missing, 
                              ref isVisible,
                              ref missing,
                              ref missing, 
                              ref missing, 
                              ref missing);

Word.WdStatistic stat = Word.WdStatistic.wdStatisticPages;
num = aDoc.ComputeStatistics(stat, ref missing);

label3.Text = "Page Count :"+aDoc.ComputeStatistics(stat, ref missing).ToString();
GC.Collect();
```

Now, I want to print the opened word file on the click event of a button, Any idea?

Comment: Refer to http://www.experts-exchange.com/Programming/Languages/.NET/Visual_Basic.NET/Q_25201838.html or http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/Forums/Thread/46030/

Comment: You can also try this link. http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/rahul4_saxena/printing-in-asp-net/

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Quick tip (not relevant to your topic but actually C#): there's no need to write out **optional parameters** as you did above, you can use `ParameterName: parameter` to specify a parameter to a optional parameter.

Quick answer: use `Document.PrintOut()` method to print the current document. For more details about the parameters, you can take a look at [MSDN site](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff837331%28v=office.15%29.aspx) and [this site](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b9f0ke7y.aspx) for a hand-on tutorial.

Here is a simple demo:

```
public class YourClass : Form
{
    private Word.Application word = new Word.Application {Visible = false};
    private Word.Document doc;
    // where did you get this file name?
    private string fileName;

    private void Count()
    {
        // as you mentioned, you open your word document here
        doc = word.Documents.Open(fileName, ReadOnly : readOnly, Visible: isVisible);
    }

    // in your button click handler, just call PrintOut() function
    private void ButtonClickHandler(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // if doc == null, open the document
        if (doc == null)
        {
            // here i assume fileName has been assigned
            doc = word.Documents.Open(fileName, ReadOnly : readOnly, Visible: isVisible);
        }

        doc.PrintOut();
    }
}
```

Comment: I can't call the printOut() because my code for opening word file is in a function named public int Count(filename){
//code above
}

Comment: how about you declare your `Application` and `Document` object outside as Class wide private object, and call `Open` in that function? This way you are able to use that `Document` class wide.

Comment: sorry I'm kinda new to c# so I really don't know what is happening. haha can you give me an insight of what you are talking? Forgive me for being noob.

Comment: And oh I tried the one you gave. And it's working. I just want to call that printOut() on a click event.

Comment: oh I kind of understand what you mean. may I know where did you get your fileName?

Comment: fileName is from the openFileDialog. here's my pastebin so you can check furthermore and be enlightened sorry my bad http://pastebin.com/py6HgM5f

Comment: I pasted the code for browse file. that's where the fileName came from.

Comment: and or the public int Count(string fileName) I'm counting all the pages of the opened document.

Comment: what's inside your count? is it the code you pasted in your question? but from the pastebin, it seems you had it done in your else statement.

Comment: the is if the answer in file dialog is Yes the count function will come at place.

Comment: that's my code for browsing files if the user choose no it will count the page and show the print button. if yes the file will be opened in microsoft word

Comment: if that is the case, the declare your `Word.Application` and `Word.Document` object outside the function, then they can be used in other functions.

Comment: I see. okay will try that out. Just like what you did?

Comment: I would love that. what's ur email?

Comment: i dont know how to add here haha here's my facebook account https://www.facebook.com/rockyruther haha

Comment: You'll need invoke "doc.Activate();" before calling "doc.PrintOut()".

Answer (score -1):

Use the RawPrintHelper. Follow the link below:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/322091

below is the code to send file to the printer for printing:

```
//Send file for Printing
RawPrinterHelper.SendFileToPrinter(PrinterName, FileName);

//Send string to print
RawPrinterHelper.SendStringToPrinter(PrinterName, sData);
```